# Get the count of particular string that matches pattern from variables

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables

I have a variable values as below. I want to get the length of this variable but i want it to count only the value that starts with `https://`

```
print(non_empty_lines)
['--POPS number', 'https://36354_test.sql', '--Second Script', 'https://36354_TEST_2.sql']
```

if i print the `len` of `non_empty_lines` it should just give me `2` as it has got two values that starts with `https://`

I just tried below option but it doesnt work. Any help on this please.

```
print(len(non_empty_lines.find('https://')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try using list comprehension and len()

```
non_empty_lines = ['--POPS number', 'https://36354_test.sql', '--Second Script', 'https://36354_TEST_2.sql']
has_http = [line for line in non_empty_lines if line.startswith("https://")]
print(len(has_http))
```

The output should be

```
2
```

and if you just print the list

```
print(has_http)
```

The output should be

```
['https://36354_test.sql', 'https://36354_TEST_2.sql']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` built-in:

```
lines = [
    "--POPS number",
    "https://36354_test.sql",
    "--Second Script",
    "https://36354_TEST_2.sql",
]

print(sum(line.startswith("https://") for line in lines))
```

Prints

```
2
```